# Open specific page of a pdf in iFrame on iPad

Tags: ipad, iframe

I am trying to open a specific page of a pdf (for example, http://cb.vu/unixtoolbox.pdf#page=14) inside an iFrame. While it works on desktop browsers, it is not working on an iPad.

Also noticing that, this does not work on the iPad even without the iFrame if I want to go the page 14 by typing http://cb.vu/unixtoolbox.pdf#page=14 directly in the address bar of mobile safari.

Has any of you came across this problem? If so, how did you solve it?

Thanks a lot for any help!